# Show menu sub-elements on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created an HTML page with a navigation menu in a sidebar. Some of the menu element contain sub-elements. What I am trying to do is:

Hide all sub-elements (this I managed)
If I hover over an element that has sub-element, show the sub-elements.
If I hover over an element that does not have any sub-elements, don't do anything.

I sort of know how to do this with CSS, but since this is for a jQuery class, I want to use jQuery.

I already found a few hints on the web, but I don't really know how to apply the suggestions to my code. I am completey new to jQuery, hence any help will be much appreciated!

Here's the HTML:

```
   <nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2a</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2b</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200 px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-right: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-left: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
}
.menu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7e7d 0%,#6B737E 100%); 
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E323A;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3EB9E7 0%,#8abbd7 100%); 
}


.submenu a {

    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2E2E2 0%,#fcfff4 100%);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD0CF;
    color: black;
}

.submenu a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C5C6C5 0%,#d6dbbf 100%); 
  background-color: #C5C6C5;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

This is a jQuery snippet that I found and that seems to make sense, but I am not sure how to apply it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').hover(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'deployed'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('deployed');
      $(this).addClass('deployed');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only use jQuery to achieve this. This is how you can do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.menu > li').hover(function() {

        $(this).has('.submenu').children('.submenu').stop().slideToggle();

    });

});
```

So what the above code does is that on hover, it checks if the hovered element has a children with a class '.submenu' and if it does, then it selects that children and toggles it with a sliding effect. Instead of slide toggling it you could obviously do anything with it like adding a class.

The `.stop()` stops repetition of the sliding effect if you were to quickly toggle hover on and off several times.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question unlike these others... Basically add a mouseenter event handler, check if the li has a submenu, if so add the active class to it.

Modify it to how you want them to close

```js
$('.menu li').mouseenter(function() {
  if($(this).has('.submenu')) {
   $(this).find('.submenu').addClass('active');
  }
 });
  
  $('.menu .submenu').mouseleave(function() {
   $('.submenu').removeClass('active');
 });
```

```css
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200 px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-right: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-left: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
}
.menu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7e7d 0%,#6B737E 100%); 
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E323A;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3EB9E7 0%,#8abbd7 100%); 
}


.submenu a {

    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2E2E2 0%,#fcfff4 100%);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD0CF;
    color: black;
}

.submenu a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C5C6C5 0%,#d6dbbf 100%); 
  background-color: #C5C6C5;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
 transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.submenu.active {
 max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Subpage 2a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subpage 2b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subpage 2c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. Where would I have to put the mouseleave function to close the menu again when moving the mouse away? Inside the if statement? I know it would be easer to use a toggle, but I have to do it by adding/removing a class.

Comment: You can just put a similar mouseleave function underneath. Not sure about your requirements for closing the menu. I edited answer to show when the mouse leaves they all close

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it all makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed below then the sample works like below snippet (for demo purpose, remove position:fixed from ):

**1.** bind hover event to `$('nav > ul > li > a')` intead of `$('#nav > li > a')`, but it slideDown the sub menu when the mouse hover on the sub menu, so need to change it to `$('nav > ul > li')`

**2.** replace `max-height:0` with `display:none`; Below is the reason using display instead of max-height.

[Check JQuery API:](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

As JQuery Defined:

> The .slideToggle() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide up or down, appearing to
>   reveal or conceal the items. If the element is initially displayed, it
>   will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is
>   saved and restored as needed. If an element has a display value of
>   inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed
>   inline. When the height reaches 0 after a hiding animation, the
>   display style property is set to none to ensure that the element no
>   longer affects the layout of the page.

**3.** in the handler of `hover` bind, execute `$('ul', $(this)).slideToggle( "slow" );`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('nav > ul > li').hover(function(){
      $('ul', $(this)).slideToggle( "slow" );
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200 px;
    top: 80px;
    left: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-right: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-left: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
}
.menu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7e7d 0%,#6B737E 100%); 
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E323A;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3EB9E7 0%,#8abbd7 100%); 
}


.submenu a {

    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2E2E2 0%,#fcfff4 100%);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD0CF;
    color: black;
}

.submenu a:hover {

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C5C6C5 0%,#d6dbbf 100%); 
  background-color: #C5C6C5;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2a</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2b</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a few adjustments to your code, mostly targeting, but also a minor CSS change.

Change `#nav` to `.menu` in all jQuery code so that the correct elements are targeted.

Change `max-height: 0;` to `display: none;` in the `.submenu` CSS so your submenu can be shown . You can also set a min-width for your menu so the width doesn't change when the submenu is visible.

You may also choose to modify your jQuery code or add a mouseout handler so the submenu is hidden when you are no longer over the parent/submenu.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vbryo27z/9/

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! Would you mind explaining why the width of the menu changes when I open/close the menu? How can I make sure it always stays the same?

Comment: The width changes because your submenu items are wider than the parent menu items. The chosen answer actually contains a more elegant fix (rather than just the minimum change required to get it working). It adds an "active" class to set `max-height` when the submenu is displayed. I would set it to `auto` rather than `200px` but it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

We add `const subMenu = $(this).find('.submenu');` to find `.submenu` element with `.menu > li` selector.

Then we add our logic to toggle class via `addClass` and `removeClass`. I have also included second callback for `.hover`, which is hoverout.

`$(selector).hover(hoverInCallback, hoverOutCallback);`

Since I did not want to mess your css I have added only following rule

`.submenu.visible {
  overflow: initial;
  max-height: auto;
}`

Hope this helps!

**Here is working example.**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.menu > li').hover(function() {
      const subMenu = $(this).find('.submenu');
      
      subMenu.addClass('visible');
  },
  // hoverout
  function() {
      const subMenu = $(this).find('.submenu');
      
      subMenu.removeClass('visible');
  });
  
});
```

```css
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200 px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-right: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-left: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
}
.menu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7e7d 0%,#6B737E 100%); 
    border-top: 1px solid #9AA2B2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2E323A;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3EB9E7 0%,#8abbd7 100%); 
}


.submenu a {

    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #E2E2E2 0%,#fcfff4 100%);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CFD0CF;
    color: black;
}

.submenu a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C5C6C5 0%,#d6dbbf 100%); 
  background-color: #C5C6C5;
}

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}

.submenu.visible {
  overflow: initial;
  max-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Page 2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2a</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2b</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Subpage 2c</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```